# Continuous comparison between two Finsler norms?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $(E,F_1)$ be a Finsler vector bundle over a manifold $M$. (See precise definition below).
Let $F_2$ be another Finsler function (norm) on $E$.

For any $p \in M \, , \, F_1|_{E_p}:E_p \to \mathbb{R}$ is a norm on a finite dimensional vector space. Hence the corresponding unit sphere $\mathbb{S^p_1}=\{v_p \in E_p |F_1(v_p)=1 \}$ is compact. So $F_2$ attains a minimium on $\mathbb{S^p_1}$. Thus we obtain a function $m:M \to \mathbb{R}$ via $m(p) = \min\{F_2(v_p) | v_p \in \mathbb{S^p_1}\}$

**Question:**

Is $m$ always continuous?

**Remarks:**

(1) I am quite sure $m$ is not *smooth* in general. For example, if $E=TM$ and $F_i$ are the Finsler norms induces by two Riemannian metric $g_1,g_2$, then [a calculation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379188/the-riemannian-distance-function-does-not-change-if-we-use-smooth-paths) shows that $m(p)=\min \lambda(G)$ where $G$ is the component matrix $g_{ij}$ of one metric w.r.t an orthonormal frame of the other.

(2) We cannot always choose a **continuous minimizing section** $s:M \to E$  ,i.e $s$ such that: $s_p \in \mathbb{S^p_1} \, , \, F_2(s_p)=m(p)$

(This follows from the above example together with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1555498/104576))

Of course, when such a continuous choice as described in (2) is possible this imediately implies continuity of $m$.

---

A Finsler vector bundle is a (smooth) vector bundle $E$ over a (smooth) manifold $M$  together with a Finsler function $F : E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every vector $v \in E$:

(1) $F$ is smooth on the complement of the zero section of $E$.

(2)        $F(v) \ge 0$ with equality if and only if $v = 0$ (positive definiteness).

(3)
 $F(\lambda v) = |\lambda| F(v)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (homogeneity).

(4)
$F(v + w) \le  F(v) + F(w)$ for every $w$ which is in the same fiber with v (subadditivity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**
Yes, $m$ is always continuous.

**Remark:**
Your definition of a Finsler function is contradictory.
In part (3) you should either assume $F(\lambda v) = |\lambda| F(v)$ or restrict to $\lambda\geq0$.
Some authors do not require Finsler functions to be symmetric.

**Details:**
Suppose $m$ is not continuous.
Then there is $p\in M$ and a sequence $(p_i)$ converging to $p$ so that $\lim_{i\to\infty}m(p_i)\neq m(p)$.
A priori (from considerations of continuous of functions on metric spaces alone), the limit $\ell:=\lim_{i\to\infty}m(p_i)$ can be anything on $[0,\infty]$.

For each $i$, let us pick $v^i\in E_{p_i}$ so that $F_1(v^i)=1$ and $F_2(v^i)=m(p_i)$.
We can identify the tangent spaces near $p$ (this comes from the very definition of a bundle) and pass to a subsequence to assume that the vectors $v^i$ converge to a limit $v\in E_p$.
Since $F_1$ and $F_2$ depend continuously on the base point, we have $F_1(v)=1$ and $F_2(v)=\ell\in(0,\infty)$.
By the definition of $m$ we must have $\ell\geq m(p)$.
Since we have assumed $\ell\neq m(p)$ (to the end of finding a contradiction), we can conclude that $m(p)<\ell<\infty$.

Let $u\in E_p$ be a vector with $F_1(u)=1$ and $F_2(u)=m(p)$.
With the aforementioned identification we can consider $u=u^i$ as a vector on $E_{p_i}$ as well.
It follows from the continuous dependence of $F_1$ and $F_2$ on the base point that $\lim_{i\to\infty}F_1(u^i)=1$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty}F_2(u^i)=m(p)$.
But $F_2(u^i)\geq F_1(u^i)m(p_i)$, so
$$
m(p)
=
\lim_{i\to\infty}F_2(u^i)
\geq
\lim_{i\to\infty}F_1(u^i)
\times
\lim_{i\to\infty}m(p_i)
=
1\times\ell
>
m(p).
$$
This is impossible.

(This proof could have been organized differently, of course. I hope this conveys the key ideas clearly enough.)

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your remark, I edited the question acoordingly.  I think your proof is correct. Some minor comments: 1) It should be $F_2(v^i)=m(p_i)$ instead of $F_1$. 2) A-priori the limit $\lim_{i\to\infty}m(p_i)$ might not exists at all. (Discontinuity can happen either if the limit exists and is different from $m(p)$ or if it does not exists at all). However, in your proof you actually showed a limit always exists, by taking a subsequence of the $v^i$.

Comment: @AsafShachar, you are welcome. I corrected the typo. It follows from the definition of discontinuity that the limit is different from $m(p)$ or does not exist at all. But after passing to a subsequence (a step which I left implicit), one can assume that there is a limit in $[0,\infty]$. (Every real sequence has a monotonous subsequence, so you can assume even more than convergence.) It is convenient that in case of discontinuity there still is a sequence with a limit.